# Process Data From Multiple Nodes of Varying Size and Data Type Firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is what the "moods" node of my Firebase database looks like on the Firebase console with the first node fully expanded. I want to go through the data to get the first three as strings, the "position" key as an int and the "venues" as an array or ArrayList, ideally without referring to each individual element by its key (eg. "KIsbAUkPflh5JH_ig24"). I want to do this for each element.

```
 -moods
 -KIsbAUkPflh5JH_ig24
      icon: "http://www.imagesource.com/0"
      image: "http://www.imagesource.com/1"
      name:  "Happy"
      position:  1
 -venues 
      100: true
      262: true
      45: false
      68: false
      82: true
 +KIxKyLALCKFV67azkK7
 +KIxL-z474lwJ2aR86NU
 +KIxQQOow2pVeMeqVpL1
 +KIxU-Umxac4aG_swuNt
```

**So far I have tried**

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.

  Log.d(TAG, dataSnapshot.toString());
  Log.d(TAG, "ChildrenCount == " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
  for(DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
   {
        Log.d(TAG, d.getKey() + " : " + d.getValue(String.class));
   }
   dataSnapshot.getValue(ArrayList.class);
 }
```

**Which prints:**

```
(FULL JSON DOCUMENT ON THIS LINE)

ChildrenCount == 5

icon : http://www.imagesource.com/0

image : http://www.imagesource.com/1

name : Happy

D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

E/UncaughtException: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to >convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
```

How would I go about parsing this data into it's different types, without explicitly stating which data type I am looking for from each node? Is this possible or should I just make a big switch statement and deal with each item by its key?

Comment: I think it should be Log.d(TAG, d.getKey() + " : " + d.getValue().toString()); because your line is converting a long to string, which gives you the error.

Comment: Your data structure is not clear. Please include the actual JSON as text, which you can get by clicking the export button in your Firebase Console.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to make a large switch statement like this:

```
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this locations is updated.

        int childCount = (int)dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();

        final String [] icons = new String[childCount];
        final String [] images = new String[childCount];
        /*final String []*/ moodNames = new String[childCount];
        final Bitmap [] backgroundBitmaps = new Bitmap[childCount];
        venueKeysInEachButton = new String[childCount][];
        int moodCounter = 0;

        //For each mood in moods
        for(DataSnapshot mood :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            //Get all of the information about the mood
            String icon = "";
            String image = "";
            String moodName = "";
            int position = 0;

            for (DataSnapshot moodChild : mood.getChildren()) {

                String key = moodChild.getKey();
                switch (key) {
                    case "icon":
                        icon = moodChild.getValue(String.class);
                        Log.i(TAG, key + " : " + icon);
                        break;
                    case "image":
                        image = moodChild.getValue(String.class);
                        Log.i(TAG, key + " : " + image);
                        break;
                    case "name":
                        moodName = moodChild.getValue(String.class);
                        Log.i(TAG, key + " : " + moodName);
                        break;
                    case "position":
                        position = moodChild.getValue(Long.class).intValue() - 1;
                        Log.i(TAG, key + " : " + position);
                        break;
                    case "venues":

                        Log.i(TAG, key + " : " + moodChild.getValue().toString());

                        ArrayList<String> venueKeys = new ArrayList<String>();
                        Iterable<DataSnapshot> venueSnapshot = moodChild.getChildren();
                        for (DataSnapshot venue : venueSnapshot){
                            Log.d(TAG, venue.toString());
                            if(venue.getValue(Boolean.class)){
                                venueKeys.add(venue.getKey());
                            }
                        }

                        venueKeysInEachButton[moodCounter] = new String [venueKeys.size()];
                        venueKeys.toArray(venueKeysInEachButton[moodCounter]);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error when parsing DataSnapshot, key is : " + key);
                        break;
                }
            }

            icons[position] = icon;
            images[position] = image;
            moodNames[position] = moodName;
            moodCounter++;

        }
    }
```